# Angular 7 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error just only having app.component

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error even after commenting out all the codes and leaving just app.component

```
ERROR in : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at stripGeneratedFileSuffix (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18184:25)
    at AotSummaryResolver.isLibraryFile (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25479:44)
    at ToJsonSerializer.visitStaticSymbol (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23444:38)
    at ToJsonSerializer.visitStaticSymbol (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23453:34)
    at ToJsonSerializer.visitStaticSymbol (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23453:34)
    at ToJsonSerializer.visitStaticSymbol (C:\Code\Core.PerformanceReporting\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23453:34)
```

Comment: could you share the code or recreate on stackblitz

Comment: this is the compile error for the project. it compiles successfull first time and again when i make some small change for eg. add a simple semicolon and save. it compiles and throws the above error

Comment: what version of angular / angular cli you're using

Comment: angular version 6

Comment: @MukilDeepthi - did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm working on a project which has exactly the same issue.